# MATLAB fixed-point function "fi" equivalent in Python

Tags: python, matlab

MATLAB has a function "**fi**" for representing fractions in fixed-point scheme. Its syntax is

```
fi(fraction, sign, word_length, fraction_length).
```

For example, to represent -0.4 in fixed-point with 8-bit word_length and 7-bit fraction_length, it returns the following:

```
fixed_number = fi(-0.4, 1, 8, 7) = -0.3984
fixed_number.int = -51
fixed_number.bin = 11001101
```

**Query**: Can we do similar in Python? Is there any function for performing this?

Comment: [`decimal.Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) is python's (arguably more useful) fixed point number type.

Answer (score 2):

[Python's rig library](https://pypi.org/project/rig/) is useful for this purpose. It supports both floating to fixed and fixed to floating point conversion.

[Example](https://rig.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ten_lines/type_casts_doctest.html):

```
>>> from rig.type_casts import float_to_fp, fp_to_float

>>> # Create a function to convert a float to a signed fractional
>>> # representation with 8 bits overall and 4 fractional bits (S3.4)
>>> s34 = float_to_fp(signed=True, n_bits=8, n_frac=4)
>>> hex(int(s34(0.5)))
'0x8'
>>> hex(int(s34(-7.5)))
'-0x78'

>>> # ...and make a function to convert back again!
>>> f4 = fp_to_float(n_frac=4)
>>> f4(0x08)
0.5
>>> f4(-0x78)
-7.5
```

Comment: This answer would be better if it contained a link to the mentioned library and an example of usage.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend **fxpmath** module, it is very similar to `fi` function.

Git repo url: https://github.com/francof2a/fxpmath

```py
from fxpmath import Fxp

x = Fxp(-0.4, True, 8, 7)   # (val, signed, n_word, n_frac)

print(x())                  # original format = float
print(x.val)                # (raw) int value
print(x.bin())              # binary representation
```

Results:

```
-0.3984375
-51
11001101
```